# ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest

Hi I am getting an error when i run the pytest file

> ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
> pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --browser chrome
> inifile: None
> rootdir: C:\Users\Prabhakar\PycharmProjects\nopecommerceApp

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
@pytest.fixture()
def setUp(browser):
 global driver
 if browser == 'chrome':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    print("***** Launching chrome browser ******")
elif browser == 'firefox':
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    print("***** Launching Firefox browser ******")
return driver
def pytest_addoption(parser):
   parser.addoption('--browser')
@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):
  return request.config.getoption('--browser')
```

Comment: Have you added driver path ?
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver1\chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: I directly added the driver in c drive into python scripts

Comment: @Akzy My code worked. it was a issue in file name error

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes ago, I had the same error and didn't find a quick solution online. I was rushing to get some stuff done, so I immediately deleted the local project and cloned it again. It worked so well for me

> git clone [REPOSITORY]